# Integrability of a function (Darboux)

Tags: real-analysis

Question:

> 1. Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and assume $0 \leq f(x) \leq B$ for  $x\in [a,b]$.   Show that 
>      $$U(f^2,P) -L(f^2,P) \leq 2B\ ( U(f,P) - L(f,P) )$$
>      for all partitions $P$ of $[a,b]$.
> 2. Show that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then so is $f^2$ [no positivity assumption here].

I found this hint buried in the latex file my prof gave me.

> (Hint: $f(x)^2 -f(y)^2 = (f(x) + f(y)) \cdot (f(x) -f(y))$.)

It really wasn't easy to put it to good use...

$$\begin{align}
U(f^2,P) -L(f^2,P) &= (U(f,p) + L(f,p)) \cdot (U(f,p) - L(f,p)) \\
&\leq (|U(f,p)| + |L(f,p)|) \cdot (U(f,p) - L(f,p))
\end{align}$$

We know $|U(f,p)|\geq |L(f,p)|$, and since $f(x) \leq B$, $|f(x)| \leq B$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ where $B \in \mathbb {R}$.

Knowing that  $|L(f,p)| \leq |U(f,p)|\leq |f(x)| \leq B$, we get:

$$(B + B) \cdot (U(f,p) - L(f,p)) = 2B\ (U(f,P) - L(f,P))$$

Hence $U(f^2,P)-L(f^2,P) \leq 2B\ (U(f,P) - L(f,P))$.

Anyone agree with me?

---

Part 2)

*Theorem:* Let $f:[a,b] \to [c,d]$ be Daraboux-integrable and $g:[c,d] \to \mathbb {R}$ be continuous. Then the composition $g \circ f$ is Daraboux-integrable.

Let $g=x^2$, so that $g \circ f=f^2$. Since $g$ is continous on $[c,d]$ for all $c,d \in \mathbb {R}$, $f^{2}$ is integrable as long as $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ by the theorem above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\color{red} \cdots$ $U(f,p)$ generally refers to the "upper sum," not a step function.  Instead, define two step functions $s$ and $t$ over a partition $P$ such that $s(x) \le f(x) \le t(x)$.  Let $s$ be maximal while still requiring $s(x) \le f(x)$ and let $t$ be minimal.  Then $s^2$ and $t^2$ are step functions corresponding to $f^2$.

Your comment that "hence $U(f,p) \le B$" threw me off a bit.  You can simply conclude that $t(x) \le B$ since $f(x) \le B$ and $t$ is a step function taking values on $f$.

---

And I would recommend turning the inequality $[B+B]( U(f,p) - L(f,p) ) \le 2B ( U(f,p) - L(f,p) )$ into an equality.

Both parts give correct proofs (if we replace the instances of $U(f,p)$ and $L(f,p)$ appropriately with $s$ and $t$).  However, it sounds like your professor may want you to prove the second part directly from the first.  If that is the case, simply pay attention to the fact that $U(f,p) - L(f,p) \to 0$ as the partitions become finer, while $2B$ is a fixed constant.  $\color{red} *$ *But* be careful, because you have to drop the positivity assumption for this part.

---

There are a few lines in there which are unnecessary.  For instance, you write:

> $U(f,p)|≥|L(f,p)|$ since $f(x)≤B |f(x)|≤B$ for all $x∈[a,b]$ where $B∈\mathbb R$

While all these statements are true, and you should definitely mention $U(f,p) \ge L(f,p)$, the second part is both unnecessary and trivial and makes the proof a bit messy (since it makes it sound like the first statement follows from the second).  So I would recommend getting rid of the part beyond "since."

You also write:

> $|L(f,p)|≤|U(f,p)|≤|f(x)|≤B$

By using the absolute value signs, do you mean to be taking the maximum value of the functions?

Comment: I am very bad at giving proofs... usually i can find right idea but i always get very poor marks  how do i make this argument better?

Comment: In your first line, don't you mean that $f\le B$ implies $U(f,P)\le B(b-a)$?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Wait...I was thinking the whole time that $U(f,P)$ denoted a step function $\ge f$ for all points, not the upper sum.  If that's the case, then the whole proof may have to be rewritten.

Comment: Is your claim that $s^2$ and $t^2$ are upper/lower step functions for $f^2$ assuming that $f$ is nonnegative?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Yes.  Feel free to edit if you see something wrong.  I think my answer's a bit disorganized.

Comment: @Andrew:  By using the absolute value signs, do you mean to be taking the maximum value of the functions? 

Thos brackets are what we have i thought those where absolute value from the triangle inequality?

Comment: @user70337 Absolute value of real numbers or "max" of functions?  In general, $|t(x)| \le |f(x)|$ is not true, but the inequality *is* true if we are using it to denote the maximum value that the function reaches.  You may be thinking $s(x) \le f(x) \le t(x) \le B$ instead.

Comment: but why cant i say that Absolute value of $(f(x)) \leq B $ for all $x \in [a,b]$ ? the max value of f(x) would be equal to B as that is hwo it defined no? i understand what your talking about though and i will fix it.

Comment: @user70337 You can, but it's trivial and unnecessary, given the nonnegativity condition.

Comment: $\color{red} \cdots$ $U(f,p)$ generally refers to the "upper sum," not a step function.  Instead, define two step functions $s$ and $t$ over a partition $P$ such that $s(x) \le f(x) \le t(x)$.  Let $s$ be maximal while still requiring $s(x) \le f(x)$ and let $t$ be minimal.  Then $s^2$ and $t^2$ are step functions corresponding to $f^2$.

so i don't completely understand this are you saying that i should write $$U(f^2,P) -L(f^2,P) \leq 2B\ ( U(f,P) - L(f,P) )$$ as $(s^{2},P) - (t^{2},P) \leq 2B\ (s,P) - (t,P)$ ? if not how do i show where the upper n lower sums must be?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8951/discussion-between-andrew-salmon-and-user70337)

Answer (score 1):

The first question (without positivity assumpation) is answerred [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395051/upper-and-lower-integration-inequality/403506#403506).

As for the second part it is easy modulo results of the first question. Let $\small P$ be some partition of $\small P$. Since $\small f$ is integrable then 
$$
\small
\lim\limits_{\mu(P)\to 0}(U(f,P)-L(f,P))=0
$$
From inequality of the first question we get 
$$
\small
0\leq \lim\limits_{\mu(P)\to 0}(U(f^2,P)-L(f^2),P)\leq \lim\limits_{\mu(P)\to 0}2B(U(f,P)-L(f),P))=2B\lim\limits_{\mu(P)\to 0}(U(f,P)-L(f),P))=0
$$
Hence $\small \lim_{\mu(P)\to 0)}(U(f^2,P)-L(f^2),P)=0$. Since partition $\small P$ was arbitrary this means that $\small f^2$ is integrable.

Comment: I noticed your answer to the other question i was hopeing to see it done in a simpler fashion if i could use ( Darboux) im intrested in both ways of solving the problem if that is alright? Thank you for such a good answer!

Comment: @user70337 Assuming positivity your proof is ok, so I don't see a problem here. Without positivity my proof is almost the same. You can skip addendum there because I see already familiar with those properties. As for the second question my proof here is quite simple, and usage of general result (as you did) is redundant.